# i cant boot my installed ubuntu

Tags: boot

i can't boot the installed ubuntu 12.0 on my toshiba sateliteL750 . it only boot from the preinstalled os (win7) and i want it to be alongside with different disk partition.
  there is no multiple option to boot for other oss.

Comment: When you installed Ubuntu, where did you install grub? You should have installed it on /dev/sda (Primary hard disk).

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu came with GRUB on it, so it will only load if it's the primary boot device.

Go into the BIOS and into the Boot Device Order.

Select Ubuntu's drive (It's usally `/dev/sda2`, but to make sure, run a LiveCD and run in a terminal `fdisk`) and put it in the order as the first boot device.

Save the changes and reboot.

Hopefully GRUB will come up and you will be able to choose between Windows and Ubuntu.

Hope this helps!!!